# C++ vector segmentation error when accessing the first element

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been having a really hard time with this error, as I've tried everything I could to fix it to no avail.

I'm building a genetic algorithm for my C++ class and I have to store a lot of individuals in a container of some sort, so I chose to make a custom container class called "GenePool" to hold instances of "IndivPtr" (which is a typedef smart pointer to "Individual").

These individuals are stored in its internal vector, and I overloaded the subscript operator ([]) to access its elements.

However, my program barely runs because after filling the vector with elements, it always causes a segmentation error when trying to access the FIRST element from the vector, and it throws an std::out_of_range exception!

I would like to know in this case how I can access elements from my vectors without causing such error.

Here is the code for GenePool:

```
#include "GenePool.h"
#include "Controller.h"
#include <algorithm>

GenePool::GenePool()
{
    // Default empty constructor
    individualList.reserve(10000);
}

GenePool::~GenePool()
{
    //deleteAll();
}

void GenePool::sortPool()
{
    // Sort the vector from greatest to least using GreatertThanSort
    // The third parameter is the address of the GreaterThanSort's greater than function for a GreaterThanSort for Individuals
    std::sort(individualList.begin(), individualList.end(), &GreaterThanSort::greaterThan);
}

Individual& GenePool::operator[](int index)
{
    // Put exception handling here somewhere (a throw statement)
    return *individualList.at(index);
}

// Get an individual from the list between index 0 and index size - 1
Individual& GenePool::getRandIndiv()
{
    return this->operator[](Controller::getRandNumInRange(0, this->size() - 1));
}

void GenePool::pushBackIndiv(const IndivPtr& indiv)
{
    individualList.push_back(indiv);
}

void GenePool::pushBackIndiv(Individual& indiv)
{
    Individual * p2Indiv = &indiv;

    if(LangermannPoint * pIndivL = dynamic_cast<LangermannPoint*>(p2Indiv))
    {
        IndivPtr pL(new LangermannPoint(*pIndivL));
        individualList.push_back(pL);
    }
    else if(CurveParams * pIndivC = dynamic_cast<CurveParams*>(p2Indiv))
    {
        IndivPtr pC(new CurveParams(*pIndivC));
        individualList.push_back(pC);
    }
}

int GenePool::size() const
{
    return individualList.size();
}

void GenePool::clear()
{
    if(!individualList.empty())
    {
        individualList.clear();
    }
}

void GenePool::addContentsOf(GenePool& other)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i)
    {
        pushBackIndiv(other[i]);
    }
}
```

Before this subscript is called, the vector is filled:

```
    // Initialize a population of individuals with randomly generated     parameters.
    if(getProblemType() == Controller::OPTIMIZATION)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < getInitPopSize(); ++i)
        {
            population.pushBackIndiv(IndivPtr(new LangermannPoint(getRandFloatInRange(0.0f, LangermannPoint::POINT_BOUND),
                                                                  getRandFloatInRange(0.0f, LangermannPoint::POINT_BOUND))));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < getInitPopSize(); ++i)
        {
            population.pushBackIndiv(IndivPtr(new CurveParams(getRandFloatInRange(-CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND, CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND),
                                                              getRandFloatInRange(-CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND, CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND),
                                                              getRandFloatInRange(-CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND, CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND),
                                                              getRandFloatInRange(-CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND, CurveParams::PARAM_BOUND))));
        }
    }
```

Here is the invocation to the subscript operator that always crashes:

```
bool Controller::terminationCondition()
{
    population.sortPool();
    // After sorting, the first is the fittest
    if(generationCount <= 1)
    {
        setSolution(population[0]);
        return false;
    }
    else if(getSolution() < population[0] && generationCount < MAX_GEN_COUNT)
    {
        setSolution(population[0]);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in pushBackIndiv you should add an else for the case of error where it is not LangermannPoint or CurveParams. It seems the problem is not here but you should add that in it will help you.

Second, in operator[](int index), before accessing an element check if the requested index won't give you an out-of-range. You can check this comparing with individualList.size().

Also call size() to see if you actually have elements in the list.

Comment: OH WOW! I thought the whole time my situation was complicated; turns out the elements weren't event being added to the list in the first place!

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: So I caught the exception and checked the size to see that the vector had a size of 0 at runtime, which meant that I never initialized the value for its size!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it turns out that the real reason why I kept getting this error was because of a silly mistake on my part: I forgot to initialize the size of the population, so it never added elements to the vector when I thought it did.

But thankfully, I learned all about segmentation errors through investigating this error and how to make a vector of abstract data types :)